# Use php to hide anchor text on Wordpress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am a noob at PHP & am trying to create a wordpress template using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. The template does mostly what I want it to do but I need to hide the anchor text (the text that says BIO) so that it does not show on the page unless there is information entered into the coach_bio_1 field. The field data is wrapped in a div that shows with fancybox when the link is clicked.
Here is the code, I realize that this is probably a simple fix, thanks for your help

```
    <div class="coach_info">

            <div class="coach_pic"><img src="<?php the_field('coach_pic_1'); ?>" /></div>
            <div class="coach_content">
                <p class="coach_title"><?php the_field('coach_name_1'); ?></p><br />
                <p><?php the_field('coach_title_1'); ?></p><br />
                <p><?php the_field('coach_email_1'); ?></p>
                <a href="#bio_1" class="fancybox">BIO</a>
                <div style="display:none;">
                <div id="bio_1">
                <?php the_field('coach_bio_1'); ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- coach_info -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
<?php
if ( get_field('coach_bio_1') ) {
?>
    <a href="#bio_1" class="fancybox">BIO</a>
    <div id="bio_1">
        <?php the_field('coach_bio_1'); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Worked! I still had to wrap the <a> in a style="display: none" div so it would not show until the fancybox was called.